# Problem with Pine-Script self-referencing variables

Tags: pine-script

I have problem understanding following Pine-Script snippet, please help.

```
//@version=4
study('test')
f = 0.0
d = 0.0
d := nz(f[1])
f := d+1
plot(d)
plot(f)
```

In the above code, variable d's value is "[0, 1, 2 ...]", f is "[1, 2, 3 ...]", why is this? I am expecting "d=[0, 0, 0 ...] f = [1, 1, 1]", please help explain, thanks.

and I have another question:

```
func(price)=>
    sum = 10.0
    sum := sum + price[1]

func(close)
func(open)
```

func called bar by bar but how to save prev price variable. Implement Pine script  History Referencing Operator function.
any help thanks!

Comment: Just a side note: It would also help you if you explain why you are expecting the results like that. If you analyze the code step by step for each bar, you might see something you are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` in pinescript is called [History Referencing Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Operators#History_Referencing_Operator_.28Square_Brackets_.5B.5D.29). It refers to previous values of the variable.

When you say `f[1]`, it returns whatever `f`'s value is **one** bar ago.

It is good that you are using [nz()](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Expressions,_Declarations_and_Statements#Preventing_NaN_values.2C_Functions_na_and_nz) with `[]`, because for the very first bar, no variable has a previous value. So, when you try to access a historical value of a variable for the first time, the result will be `NaN` and `nz()` will convert `NaN` to `0`.

Another thing to know is that your code will get executed for each bar.

Let's look at your code now.

```
f = 0.0
d = 0.0
```

You declare `f` and `d` at the beginning and assign 0 to them. We can neglect this step since you are reassigning another value to them.

**First Bar**

```
d := nz(f[1])
```

Assign `f`'s value on the previous bar to `d`. `f` has **no previous value** for the first bar, so `nz()` will return `0`. So, `d = 0`.

```
f := d+1
```

f = 0 + 1 -> `f = 1`

**Second Bar**

```
d := nz(f[1])
```

Assign `f`'s value on the previous bar to `d`. `f`'s value on the **first** bar is `1`. So, `d = 1`.

```
f := d+1
```

f = 1 + 1 -> `f = 2`

**Third Bar**

```
d := nz(f[1])
```

Assign `f`'s value on the previous bar to `d`. `f`'s value on the **second** bar is `2`. So, `d = 2`.

```
f := d+1
```

f = 2 + 1 -> `f = 3`

---

**Note:** Try running the following code and you will see that it behaves exactly the same.

```
//@version=4
study('test')
f = 550.0
d = 0.0
d := nz(f[1])
f := d+1
plot(d)
plot(f)
```

The reason is, it doesn't matter what value `f` initially has. `d := nz(f[1])` will assign `f`'s value on the previous bar to `d` and for the very first bar, `f` has no previous value. Hence, `nz()` will return 0.

Then what happens for the very first bar is:

```
d := nz(f[1]) // d = 0
f := d+1      // f = 1
```

And so on..

Comment: I have another question, please have a look at my update, thanks