# PineScript History Reference Operator Troubleshooting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

I am new to PineScript, and I am trying to backtest a strategy that I created based off of some other scripts that were indicators. I believe I have written everything correctly, and it compiles with no errors. But when I add it to my chart it gives the following Study Error: "Invalid number of bars back [-1] within the history-referencing operator. The value must be >=0." Would anyone mind helping me with this issue please? This code is supposed to check multiple time frames for long/short conditions, tally the results, send the result as an alert, then enter the appropriate position and set sl/tp levels based off of surrounding order blocks. Here is my code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © nxprg8kdvr
// Created using the following scripts:
//MACD-RSI Confluence Simplified
// Custom Script from Nickafella
//"Smart Money Concepts [LuxAlgo]"
// This work is licensed under a Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International 
// (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0) https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/
// © LuxAlgo
//@version=5
strategy('Trading Strategy #1'
  , overlay = true
  , max_labels_count = 500
  , max_lines_count = 500
  , max_boxes_count = 500
  , max_bars_back = 500)

// Getting inputs
src = input(title='Source', defval=close)
fast_length = input(title='MACD Fast Length', defval=12)
slow_length = input(title='MACD Slow Length', defval=26)
signal_length = input.int(title='MACD Signal Smoothing', minval=1, maxval=50, defval=9)
sma_source = input(title='Simple MA (Oscillator)', defval=false)
sma_signal = input(title='Simple MA (Signal Line)', defval=false)
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title='RSI Length')
rsi = ta.rsi(close, len)
longcondition = macd > signal and rsi < 30
shortcondition = macd < signal and rsi > 70
cc = longcondition and nz(longcondition[1]) == false ? color.green : shortcondition 
  and nz(shortcondition[1]) == false ? color.red : color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 0)
barcolor(cc)

//Timeframes
longcondition1W = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", longcondition)
shortcondition1W = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", shortcondition)
longcondition1D = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", longcondition)
shortcondition1D = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", shortcondition)
longcondition4H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", longcondition)
shortcondition4H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", shortcondition)
longcondition1H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", longcondition)
shortcondition1H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", shortcondition)
longcondition45Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "45", longcondition)
shortcondition45Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "45", shortcondition)
longcondition15Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", longcondition)
shortcondition15Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", shortcondition)

// Majority Calculation
var int condLong = 0
var int condShort = 0
var string TF = ""
if input.bool(true, "1W", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition1W
        condLong += 1
        TF += "1WL"
    if shortcondition1W
        condShort += 1
        TF += "1WS"
    // 1D
if input.bool(true, "1D", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition1D
        condLong += 1
        TF += "1DL"
    if shortcondition1D
        condShort += 1
        TF += "1DS"
    // 4H
if input.bool(true, "4H", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition4H
        condLong += 1
        TF += "4HL"
    if shortcondition4H
        condShort += 1
        TF += "4HS"
    // 1H
if input.bool(true, "1H", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition1H
        condLong += 1
        TF += "1HL"
    if shortcondition1H
        condShort += 1
        TF += "1HS"
    // 45Min
if input.bool(true, "45Min", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition45Min
        condLong += 1
        TF += "45MinL"
    if shortcondition45Min
        condShort += 1
        TF += "45MinS"
    // 15Min
if input.bool(true, "15Min", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition15Min
        condLong += 1
        TF += "15MinL"
    if shortcondition15Min
        condShort += 1
        TF += "15MinS"

longValOne = longcondition and nz(longcondition[1])
longValTwo = condLong > condShort
shortValOne = shortcondition and nz(shortcondition[1])
shortValTwo = condShort > condLong
//---LUX SMC Code---
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
string MODE_TOOLTIP          = 'Allows to display historical Structure or only the recent ones'
string STYLE_TOOLTIP         = 'Indicator color theme'
string COLOR_CANDLES_TOOLTIP = 'Display additional candles with a color reflecting the current trend detected by structure'
string INTERNAL_OB           = 'Display internal order blocks on the chart\n\nNumber of internal order blocks to display on the chart'
string SWING_OB              = 'Display swing order blocks on the chart\n\nNumber of internal swing blocks to display on the chart'
string FILTER_OB             = 'Method used to filter out volatile order blocks \n\nIt is recommended to use the cumulative mean range method when a low amount of data is available'
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Settings
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//General
//----------------------------------------{
mode = input.string('Historical'
  , options = ['Historical', 'Present']
  , group = 'Smart Money Concepts'
  , tooltip = MODE_TOOLTIP)

style = input.string('Colored'
  , options = ['Colored', 'Monochrome']
  , group = 'Smart Money Concepts'
  , tooltip = STYLE_TOOLTIP)

show_trend = input(false, 'Color Candles'
  , group = 'Smart Money Concepts'
  , tooltip = COLOR_CANDLES_TOOLTIP)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Global variables
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var trend = 0, var itrend = 0

var top_y = 0., var top_x = 0
var btm_y = 0., var btm_x = 0

var itop_y = 0., var itop_x = 0
var ibtm_y = 0., var ibtm_x = 0

var trail_up = high, var trail_dn = low
var trail_up_x = 0,  var trail_dn_x = 0

var top_cross = true,  var btm_cross = true
var itop_cross = true, var ibtm_cross = true

var txt_top = '',  var txt_btm = ''
//----------------------------------------}
//Order Blocks
//----------------------------------------{
show_iob = input(true, 'Internal Order Blocks'
  , inline = 'iob'
  , group = 'Order Blocks'
  , tooltip = INTERNAL_OB)

iob_showlast = input.int(5, ''
  , minval = 1
  , inline = 'iob'
  , group = 'Order Blocks')

show_ob = input(false, 'Swing Order Blocks'
  , inline = 'ob'
  , group = 'Order Blocks'
  , tooltip = SWING_OB)

ob_showlast = input.int(5, ''
  , minval = 1
  , inline = 'ob'
  , group = 'Order Blocks')

ob_filter = input.string('Atr', 'Order Block Filter'
  , options = ['Atr', 'Cumulative Mean Range']
  , group = 'Order Blocks'
  , tooltip = FILTER_OB)

ibull_ob_css = input.color(color.new(#3179f5, 80), 'Internal Bullish OB'
  , group = 'Order Blocks')

ibear_ob_css = input.color(color.new(#f77c80, 80), 'Internal Bearish OB'
  , group = 'Order Blocks')

bull_ob_css = input.color(color.new(#1848cc, 80), 'Bullish OB'
  , group = 'Order Blocks')

bear_ob_css = input.color(color.new(#b22833, 80), 'Bearish OB'
  , group = 'Order Blocks')

//Order block coordinates function
n = bar_index
atr = ta.atr(200)
cmean_range = ta.cum(high - low) / n
ob_coord(use_max, loc, target_top, target_btm, target_left, target_type)=>
    min = 99999999.
    max = 0.
    idx = 1

    ob_threshold = ob_filter == 'Atr' ? atr : cmean_range 

    //Search for highest/lowest high within the structure interval and get range
    if use_max
        for i = 1 to (n - loc)-1
            if (high[i] - low[i]) < ob_threshold[i] * 2
                max := math.max(high[i], max)
                min := max == high[i] ? low[i] : min
                idx := max == high[i] ? i : idx
    else
        for i = 1 to (n - loc)-1
            if (high[i] - low[i]) < ob_threshold[i] * 2
                min := math.min(low[i], min)
                max := min == low[i] ? high[i] : max
                idx := min == low[i] ? i : idx

    array.unshift(target_top, max)
    array.unshift(target_btm, min)
    array.unshift(target_left, time[idx])
    array.unshift(target_type, use_max ? -1 : 1)

//Set order blocks
display_ob(boxes, target_top, target_btm, target_left, target_type, show_last, swing, size)=>
    for i = 0 to math.min(show_last-1, size-1)
        get_box = array.get(boxes, i)

        box.set_lefttop(get_box, array.get(target_left, i), array.get(target_top, i))
        box.set_rightbottom(get_box, array.get(target_left, i), array.get(target_btm, i))
        box.set_extend(get_box, extend.right)

        color css = na
        
        if swing 
            if style == 'Monochrome'
                css := array.get(target_type, i) == 1 ? color.new(#b2b5be, 80) : color.new(#5d606b, 80)
                border_css = array.get(target_type, i) == 1 ? #b2b5be : #5d606b
                box.set_border_color(get_box, border_css)
            else
                css := array.get(target_type, i) == 1 ? bull_ob_css : bear_ob_css
                box.set_border_color(get_box, css)

            box.set_bgcolor(get_box, css)
        else
            if style == 'Monochrome'
                css := array.get(target_type, i) == 1 ? color.new(#b2b5be, 80) : color.new(#5d606b, 80)
            else
                css := array.get(target_type, i) == 1 ? ibull_ob_css : ibear_ob_css
            
            box.set_border_color(get_box, css)
            box.set_bgcolor(get_box, css)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Order Blocks Arrays
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var iob_top = array.new_float(0)
var iob_btm = array.new_float(0)
var iob_left = array.new_int(0)
var iob_type = array.new_int(0)

var ob_top = array.new_float(0)
var ob_btm = array.new_float(0)
var ob_left = array.new_int(0)
var ob_type = array.new_int(0)

//Internal Order Block
if show_iob
    ob_coord(false, itop_x, iob_top, iob_btm, iob_left, iob_type)

//Order Block
if show_ob
    ob_coord(false, top_x, ob_top, ob_btm, ob_left, ob_type)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Order Blocks
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Set order blocks
var iob_boxes = array.new_box(0)
var ob_boxes = array.new_box(0)

//Delete internal order blocks box coordinates if top/bottom is broken
for element in iob_type
    index = array.indexof(iob_type, element)

    if close < array.get(iob_btm, index) and element == 1
        array.remove(iob_top, index) 
        array.remove(iob_btm, index) 
        array.remove(iob_left, index) 
        array.remove(iob_type, index)
        // bull_iob_break := true

    else if close > array.get(iob_top, index) and element == -1
        array.remove(iob_top, index) 
        array.remove(iob_btm, index)
        array.remove(iob_left, index) 
        array.remove(iob_type, index)
        // bear_iob_break := true

//Delete internal order blocks box coordinates if top/bottom is broken
for element in ob_type
    index = array.indexof(ob_type, element)

    if close < array.get(ob_btm, index) and element == 1
        array.remove(ob_top, index) 
        array.remove(ob_btm, index) 
        array.remove(ob_left, index) 
        array.remove(ob_type, index)
        // bull_ob_break := true

    else if close > array.get(ob_top, index) and element == -1
        array.remove(ob_top, index) 
        array.remove(ob_btm, index)
        array.remove(ob_left, index) 
        array.remove(ob_type, index)
        // bear_ob_break := true

iob_size = array.size(iob_type)
ob_size = array.size(ob_type)

if barstate.isfirst
    if show_iob
        for i = 0 to iob_showlast-1
            array.push(iob_boxes, box.new(na,na,na,na, xloc = xloc.bar_time))
    if show_ob
        for i = 0 to ob_showlast-1
            array.push(ob_boxes, box.new(na,na,na,na, xloc = xloc.bar_time))

if iob_size > 0
    if barstate.islast
        display_ob(iob_boxes, iob_top, iob_btm, iob_left, iob_type, iob_showlast, false, iob_size)

if ob_size > 0
    if barstate.islast
        display_ob(ob_boxes, ob_top, ob_btm, ob_left, ob_type, ob_showlast, true, ob_size)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//---LUX SMC Code End---
// Setting SL and TP
ob_price_lvls = array.new_float(2)
float sl_ob_price_level = array.get(ob_price_lvls, 0)
float tp_ob_price_level = array.get(ob_price_lvls, 1)

get_ob_price_level() =>
    // get entry price level
    entry_price_level = strategy.position_avg_price 
    // get the order block closest to entry price against our direction
    for j = 0 to (bar_index - array.get(iob_left, 0))
        if array.get(iob_type, j) == -strategy.position_size // if the order block is against our position
            if strategy.position_size > 0 and array.get(iob_top, j) < entry_price_level // if long and order block top is below entry level
                array.set(ob_price_lvls, 0, array.get(iob_top, j))
            if strategy.position_size < 0 and array.get(iob_btm, j) > entry_price_level // if short and order block bottom is above entry level
                array.set(ob_price_lvls, 0, array.get(iob_btm, j))
    // get the order block in our direction closest to double the difference between our entry price and sl_ob_price_level
    var float ob_dist = math.abs(array.get(ob_price_lvls, 0) - entry_price_level) * 2
    for j = 0 to (bar_index - array.get(iob_left, 0))
        if array.get(iob_type, j) == strategy.position_size // if the order block is in our direction
            if strategy.position_size > 0 and array.get(iob_btm, j) > entry_price_level 
              and array.get(iob_btm, j) - entry_price_level >= ob_dist // if long and order block bottom is above ob_price_level
                array.set(ob_price_lvls, 1, array.get(iob_btm, j))
            if strategy.position_size < 0 and array.get(iob_top, j) < entry_price_level 
              and entry_price_level - array.get(iob_top, j) >= ob_dist // if short and order block top is below ob_price_level
                array.set(ob_price_lvls, 1, array.get(iob_top, j))
// Alerts, Entry & Exit
bool longOrShort = na

alertOn = input(true, 'Alerts')
if longValOne and longValTwo and alertOn
    alert('New Long Signal - MACD/RSI', alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 1)
    longOrShort := true
    get_ob_price_level()
if shortValOne and shortValTwo and alertOn
    alert('New Short Signal - MACD/RSI', alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, 1)
    longOrShort := false
    get_ob_price_level()

// exit long and short positions
loss = close <= sl_ob_price_level
profit = close >= tp_ob_price_level

if loss or profit and longOrShort
    strategy.close(id="Exit Long", alert_message="Your long position has been closed")
if loss or profit and not longOrShort
    strategy.close(id="Exit Short", alert_message="Your short position has been closed")
```

I only use the reference operator 4 times, at line 34 twice, then once each on lines 103 and 105. I encapsulated them all in nz() since I saw [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636556/problem-with-pine-script-self-referencing-variables) that sometimes using `[]` will yield `NaN`, and `nz()` converts those values to 0. I guess this didn't fix the issue, since it persists whether I include `nz()` or not.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is because, at the beginning of the calculation, there is only one bar drawn on the chart, and you are looking for a value just before.
You can test if you are not on the first bar and launch your calculations only from the bar number 2, with :

```
if not(barstate.isfirst)
```

Then another problem show up with your loop : you can't ask for a bar value which is too far in the past (even if it has been drawn on your chart).

You can test for the number of preceding bars you want and limit it to avoid hiting the value, with :

```
if n-loc < 3000
```

Here is the modified part of your code :

```
if not(barstate.isfirst)
        if n-loc < 3000
            if use_max
                for i = 1 to (n - loc)-1
                    if (high[i] - low[i]) < ob_threshold[i] * 2
                        max := math.max(high[i], max)
                        min := max == high[i] ? low[i] : min
                        idx := max == high[i] ? i : idx
            else
                for i = 1 to (n - loc)-1
                    if (high[i] - low[i]) < ob_threshold[i] * 2
                        min := math.min(low[i], min)
                        max := min == low[i] ? high[i] : max
                        idx := min == low[i] ? i : idx

            array.unshift(target_top, max)
            array.unshift(target_btm, min)
            array.unshift(target_left, time[idx])
            array.unshift(target_type, use_max ? -1 : 1)
```

This will solve your history reference error, but there is a lot of other error in your code.